# PDF generation using HTML and CSS

Tags: php, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Please give code for PDF generation using HTML and CSS

Comment: Do you want to create a pdf file using just html and css or what are you asking?

Comment: Maybe you should add something more specific to the question.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php

Comment: SO is not a magic code-generating machine. Don't just ask people to write the code you need (just google "HTML to PDF generator" if that's what you're after). You don't learn anything by doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of my projects I am using [dompdf](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/). [Here](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/usage.php) you can find the `code` you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What's your development environment?

I have used [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) with great success. You might want to have a look at it.

Comment: The question is tagged php, so I don't think this is useful for him.

Comment: New versions of iTextSharp cannot be used in commercial applications (unless you buy a license from them). It's still OK to see it in open source projects, etc.

Comment: @captaintokyo my bad, i didn't see the 'php' tag when i posted :-(

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to generate a PDF file using just HTML and CSS code. You will need a PHP library that supports converting HTML documents to PDF documents. See this [StackOverflow question for some tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php).